# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I use `react/lib/update` method with `typescript`.

I write a definition file for it, like this:

```
declare module 'react/lib/update' {
  export default function update<S>(value: S, spec: any): S;
}
```

and, use it like this:

`import * as update from 'react/lib/update';`

but `tsc` give me an error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof 'react/lib/update'' has no compatible call signatures.`

It seems my definition file not correct. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a default export on the function `update`, you have to import it like:

```
import update from 'react/lib/update';
```